# BMP filenot correctly read by android

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bmp

The following android file is not read by my android device running (Lollipop 5.0 API 21)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2hkVMbE98w5WFJuSjUyOXNlVmc

Checking the header of the file everything looks ok ....

```
Address      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F
H'00000000: 42 4d 36 ee 02 00 00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00 28 00
H'00000001: 00 00 40 01 00 00 c8 00 00 00 01 00 18 00 00 00  
H'00000002: 00 00 00 ee 02 00 e8 03 00 00 e8 03 00 00 00 00
H'00000003: 00 01 00 00 00 00 64 49 49 64 61 5f 65 60 5f 65
...
```

Additionally, it is correctly read by my windows pc ... (!)

On android, Neither an image viewer nor the BitmapFactory library can decode correctly the image ...

Comment: how are you decoding please more detail

Comment: I tried to open the photo with many different tools in my android device like image viewers or the google photo etc... and always the result was the same ... a black picture or the app was not able to open the picture. Anyway in my program I use the bitmapFactory library and i use the BitmapFactory.decodeStream() method ... but the result is a return " D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false" message ...

Comment: i tried to load your image with "picasso" and it didn't work so i would suggest that your image has an error in android

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying ... the image looks ok in windows but I do not understand what is going on in android environment !

Comment: Your BMP file has a header indicating that it contains a palette with 16 777 216 entries. But it doesn't have a palette at all. This could be the reason it fails loading on Android.